# Excel VBA Macro to manipulate rows based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have tried searching and googling for solutions but to no avail.
I apologise now if there are solutions out there that I had missed.

(My Excel database) - Before running Macro

```
Start Date  Start Time  Number  Finish Date Finish Time
14-Jul-15   22:00   1   16-Jul-15   06:00
15-Jul-15   22:00   1   17-Jul-15   06:00
15-Jul-15   22:00   1   16-Jul-15   06:00
```

(My Excel database) - After running Macro

```
Start Date  Start Time  Number  Finish Date Finish Time
14-Jul-15   22:00   1   16-Jul-15   06:00
14-Jul-15   22:00   1   15-Jul-15   06:00
15-Jul-15   22:00   1   16-Jul-15   06:00
15-Jul-15   22:00   1   17-Jul-15   06:00
15-Jul-15   22:00   1   16-Jul-15   06:00
16-Jul-15   22:00   1   17-Jul-15   06:00
15-Jul-15   22:00   1   16-Jul-15   06:00
```

What I want the Macro to do is, 
Check if the difference of "Start Date" and "Finish Date" is more than 2.
If the difference between both is 1 or 0, it moves on to the next row of data to check. 
However, if its more than 0 or 1, it adds another row under that particular row. Then it copies the similar content but then modifying the date.

For example,

```
14-Jul-15   22:00   1   16-Jul-15   06:00
```

After the Macro, it adds under the original row.

```
14-Jul-15   22:00   1   15-Jul-15   06:00
15-Jul-15   22:00   1   16-Jul-15   06:00
```

Sorry if my question is unclear, please assist me in creating this macro.

Comment: What are the ones in the middle for and what code can you show that demonstrates any effort to try this yourself? [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Hello, really apologise that I am not putting down the details. 

http://pastebin.com/hSA3AavG


For my codes, I am not sure how I can loop through all the rows and instead of hard coding the position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting rows in a loop, always start at the bottom and work up or you risk losing your step sequence with the new rows being inserted. By stepping upwards the newly inserted rows assume row numbers that are already out of scope for the loop.

```
Sub StackOverflow()
    Dim rw As Long, i As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If (CDate(.Cells(rw, 4).Value2) - CDate(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2)) > 1 Then
                For i = 1 To (CDate(.Cells(rw, 4).Value2) - CDate(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2))
                    With .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 5)
                        .Copy
                        .Insert Shift:=xlDown   ', copyorigin:=.Cells
                    End With
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 4) = .Cells(rw + 1, 4).Value2 - (i - 1)
                    .Cells(rw + 1, 1) = .Cells(rw + 1, 4).Value2 - 1
                Next i
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

If your sample data accurately represented the actual data then the above should quickly expand your date ranges to a single day separation for each row.

Comment: Hello Jeeped,
first of all, thank you very much for taking your time to reply me.
I sincerely apologise for the rules that I have broken(still new to this site, not used to it!)
I have tested the codes that you have provided and they are working. 
However, one last request! When I ran the macro, it removed the original row. For example, if theres 1 to 3. It added in 1 to 2, 2 to 3 (but the original 1 to 3 has disappeared. Any idea on this?)

Once again, thank you so much! :)

Comment: If you had a row from 14-Jul to 17-Jul it creates a new row 16-Jul to 17-Jul, another new row 15-Jul to 16-Jul and changes the original row to 14-Jul to 15-Jul. Isn't that what your last examples demonstrates?

Comment: Ah. I think I may not have stated clearly. "After the Macro, it adds under the original row." - my original statement in my last example. I should have elaborated, so as seen in my last example I should end up with 14Jul-16-Jul, 14Jul-15Jul, 15Jul-16Jul. Anyway you can modify the codes so it ends up like this? Once again, my apologies sir.

Comment: I believe I understand the last example of desired out now. See revision above.

Comment: Thank you Mr Jeeped, this works exactly as I wanted. Have a very nice day ahead!